# Construct a Bijective Function $A \times B \rightarrow B \times A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. Prove that there exists a bijective function $A \times B \rightarrow B \times A$.

Since this chapter precedes the one concerning infinite sets, I'm assuming that these sets are finite (if there is a way to include infinite sets, I would like to know how to go about the problem).

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are finite, let $|A| = m$ and $|B| = n$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is here that I run into issues, for their are three relations that $m$ and $n$ have according to the Trichotomy law. The easiest case is where $m = n$, then a procedure to constructing a bijective function is straightforward, but I won't include it here, because I feel like there is another approach that may bypass these cases. What is a way to go about this problem? Could I just ignore the three cases, construct a function $\psi$, and show as a consequence of how $\psi$ is built, that $|A \times B| = |B \times A|$ thereby proving that $\psi$ is bijective?

Comment: The result is no harder to prove for infinite sets than finite sets. Why not just flip the elements?

Comment: take $(a,b)\mapsto(b,a)$

Comment: This is a common problem of people who start studying set theory. Things about finite sets are dealt with by "counting elements", rather than approaching the problem as it is. Then the generalization to infinite sets becomes problematic (at least before proper cardinal arithmetic is covered). Most problems of this type are actually *much* easier to approach in full generality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case it is much easier to construct such a bijection than using the abstract machinery of cardinality to show only the existence.  Consider the functions
\begin{align*}
 \varphi \colon A \times B \to B \times A, \quad (a,b) \mapsto (b,a) \\
 \psi \colon B \times A \to A \times B, \quad (b,a) \mapsto (a,b).
\end{align*}
Then $\varphi \circ \psi = \mathrm{id}_{B \times A}$ and $\psi \circ \varphi = \mathrm{id}_{A \times B}$. So $\varphi$ is bijective with $\varphi^{-1} = \psi$.

Answer (score 1):

> "Could I just ignore the three cases, construct a function ψ, and show as a consequence of how ψ is built, that |A×B|=|B×A||A×B|=|B×A| thereby proving that ψ is bijective? "

Eventually yes, well,... it depends on how constructivist you want your mathematics to be. It is always a useful exercise to make a bijection anyways:

Consider $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ as our function $f | A \times B \rightarrow B \times A $. To prove that $f$ is a bijection, show that $f$ is injective and surjective.

To see that $f$ is injective, suppose we have $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in A \times B$ and $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$. The equation $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)$ gives us $(y_1,x_1)=(y_2,x_2)$ which immediately tells us $y_1=y_2$ and $x_1=x_2$. Thus $(x_1,y_1)= (x_2,y_2) $.

To see that $f$ is surjective, for any $(x,y) \in B \times A$. We see that $(x,y)$ is hit by $f(y,x)$ for $ (y,x) \in A \times B$.